# Get a list of all labels in a tex document?

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, mac, linux

So I was wondering if `pdflatex` was writing all the labels used from a `main.tex` document.

When you're working on a hundred pages-long document like a phd dissertation, it is humanly impossible to remember all the references and point to them  :0 !

I ran into
[Tex editor able to recover all labels of a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62599/tex-editor-able-to-recover-all-labels-of-a-document)
and [How to get a list of all the labels in a LaTeX document in WinEdt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15101/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-labels-in-a-latex-document-in-winedt?r=SearchResults&s=1|98.4797)

But I figured one may also wish to get one's labels without scrolling tex code, switching editor nor move to windows. That got me blowing some dust off the manual, and produce the small script below, but still...

**The open question:**
Does tex not provide a way to do that??

Comment: All labels are written out to the `.aux` file in lines beginning `\newlabel`.  The mechanism is described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288645/579).  So looking for all instances of `\newlabel` in the `.aux` file will give you the information you are looking for.  There is also a package `showlabels` that will print out the information in the margin of your output.

Comment: Thanks... it's a shame that there's no human readable for `main.aux`, and running through the `.tex` source has the advantage providing some context. Package `showlabel` looks good :) I'd also like avoiding scrolling over and over again through the whole pdf when working on a specific part though...

Comment: If you use Window, it just to run the .aux through `find` with the `/V` switch: At a command prompt `find /V "\\newlabel" myfile.aux > myfile.lab`. Load myfile.lab in separate window in you preferred est editor. If you have several aux-files, use a `for %i in (*.aux) do find /V "\\newlabel" >>myfile.lab`-loop

Comment: @barbarabeeton oi `showlablels` is the opposition:-) don't forget to mention te `showkeys` package (which does the same thing:-)

Comment: @babarabeeton yes linux, as per the bash script below! But then if you'd `grep` through the `.aux` then you'd might as well `grep` through all the `*.tex` using `find`! and I definitely prefer the ouput :) prints me directories, filenames, line numbers, context...

Answer (score 7):

All labels are written out to the `.aux` file in lines beginning `\newlabel`. The mechanism is described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288645/579).
So looking for all instances of `\newlabel` in the `.aux` file will give you the information you are looking for.

If using the `.aux` file for reference, copy it under a new name and use the copy, since the "original" will disappear as soon as the source file is recompiled.

If you are using a *nix system, you can launch (or script) the command `grep \\newlabel *aux | main-labels.txt`.  This will produce a new file containing only the `\label` lines from the `,aux` file.  This can then be used as a reference.

A comment on the question by @Sveinung provides a similar method for Windows.

Finally, there are two packages that print out the label values on the pages where they are defined in your document:

- `showlabels`
- `showkeys`

Both packages report the values of labels that are accessed by `\ref` or `\cite` (and friends).  Both provide options to include or exclude particular types of labels, and for specifying where to position the reported labels on the output.  (See the package documentation for details.)

Answer (score 1):

A good old shell solution :)

```sh
#! /usr/bin/sh
match="grep -THn -A 2 --colour" 
pattern='\\label{.*}'

find $1 -name "*.tex" | xargs -n 1 $match $pattern
```

**Edit:** pass an optional directory argument: `$ ./labels.sh chapX`, as this may produce some output! Prints all matches with filename, line number and two lines of context (label highlighted).